# How can i derive a conditional PDF?

Tags: probability

Let X and Z be jointly continuous random variables

with joint PDF $f_{X,Z}$

When $S\in\mathbf{R}$ is a borel set with $P(Z\in S)>0$

Find the conditional PDF of X given $Z\in S$

my claim is

Let $A=\{Z\in S\}$

Then by the bayes' rule $P(A\mid X=x)=\frac{P(A)f_{X\mid A}(x)}{f_{X}(x)}
  (f_{X}(x)>0)$

Since $P(A)>0$,
  $f_{X\mid A}(x)=\frac{P(A\mid X=x)f_{X}(x)}{P(A)}$

Is this method right?

Also I'm confused with the case $f_{X}(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the method is okay.

The conditional probability mass function is defined as zero outside of the support for $X$, and implicitly $\mathsf P(Z\in\mathbf S)>0$ has been assured too, but we can be explicit about it.

$$\mathsf P(Z\in\mathbf S\mid X=x)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(Z\in\mathbf S)~f_{X}(x\mid Z\in\mathbf S)}{f_X(x)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{f_X(x)>0}\cdot\mathbf 1_{\mathsf P(Z\in\mathbf S)>0}$$

Which means the conditional probability density function is too.

$$f_X(x\mid Z\in\mathbf S)=\dfrac{f_{X}(x)~\mathsf P(Z\in\mathbf S\mid X=x)}{\mathsf P(Z\in\mathbf S)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{\mathsf P(Z\in\mathbf S)>0}\cdot\mathbf 1_{f_X(x)>0}$$

We can safely omit the second indicator function, because we really only need to be concerned about dividing by zero, rather than multiplying.